# Interrogative content clause? or what?

Tags: interrogatives, adverbial-phrases

Either due to a dent in the continuum, or as a result of my continued efforts to develop a fully functional temporal flux capacitor, yesterday a [**question**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/101803/37009) was asked which quoted almost exactly a sentence I had spoken to my own son just a day earlier:

> I won't do that no matter what are the circumstances.

I had a conversation with my son which went like this:

> *Son:* So I put it on the card. I don't have any cash under those circumstances.
>   *Father:* I wouldn't do that, no matter *what* are the circumstances!

In commentary on the cited question (not in my answer) I maintained that this construction was grammatically correct, if unusual, while another commenter averred that it was simply **wrong.**

Since the commentary includes references to things *"sounding right/wrong,"* and given my own exhortation that the questioner not disregard that criterion out of hand, I would like an answer to the following question and, if that answer is negative, to its corollary:

- Is the sentence *I won't do that no matter what are the circumstances* justifiable from a grammatical perspective?
- Why does it "sound right" (although certainly more than a little twee) to me?

Comment: Consider "no matter what" phrases, such as "I will not ignore you, *no matter what*." The phrase after that, "are the circumstances" makes no sense. So I don't think transposition will work for your example (results might be context sensitive). As of 1(a), it sound wrong to me.

Comment: _No matter_ sounds like a comparative here, to me...

Comment: I read that question and the answer; I think there is a great disagreement between the comments. I couldn't came up with a strict answer. I mean @AlanCarmac said It is wrong and you say it is right. I think we need a decisive answer !

Comment: @Cardinal Thus the instant query.

Comment: Personally, I would say "no matter what the circumstances are". However, I am not sure whether that is correct or not; I'm talking spontaneously.

Comment: @Cardinal I think you are correct. I don't think there is anything wrong with this sentence - *I won't do that no matter what the circumstances are.*

Comment: We have a recent question asking about a similar sentence, too: *[I'm gonna have to work on what else can she call me](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/93557/3281)*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. And with the same demurrer!

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84184/the-order-of-words-in-a-clause-tell-me-who-is-the-real-man-vs-tell-me-who-the-real-man-is

Comment: *no matter what the circumstances* (full stop) or *no matter what the circumstances may be*.    I will recognize you no matter what are you wearing???? Really?

Comment: no matter what the = whatever the

Comment: It is a concessive.

Comment: The salient interpretation is that this is an exhaustive conditional construction, with "no matter" as head of the adjunct with the subordinate interrogative _what_ clause as complement. But subject-auxiliary inversion is not required so it should be "no matter what the circumstances are". The meaning is I wouldn't do that _if_ the circumstances are 'x', or _if_ they are 'y' or _if_ they are 'z' and so on. It follows that whatever the circumstances are, I wouldn't do the referent of 'that'. Hence the term 'exhaustive conditional'.

Comment: @DamkerngT I guess I'm just not into *[twee](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/2011-11-18/entertainment/ct-ae-1120-twee-20111118_1_twee-indie-wilde)*.I also find the first 24 words of this question to be distracting,    unnecessary, and a waste of time.

Comment: @BillJ So in your judgment, there is no extremity, however complex, in which the sentence "I wouldn't do that, no matter _what_ are the circumstances" can be construed as grammatically correct?

Comment: @AlanCarmack Two links which might be of some benefit follow: [**1**](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Flux_capacitor) ... [**2**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fun)

Comment: If @StoneyB or F⚡︎F (or anyone) can provide an answer which authoritatively _prohibits_ subject-auxiliary inversion in the sentence, I'll slink away with my interrogative content clause. (I'm as interested in the corollary as in the question, but that's more a matter of conjecture than of grammar, I suppose.)

Comment: @BillJ Weeks later now, I realize that when I said this to my son in full pompous parental dudgeon, I was trying (and failing) to express the subjunctive _I wouldn't do that, no matter what **be** the circumstances!_ (This is also, obviously, why it "sounded" right to me.)

Answer (score -1):

Your sentence

> No matter what *are* the circumstances

sounds awkward since *interrogative + be* is usually the form of a question.
Your sentence is slightly ambiguous since it might be parsed as

> No matter, what are the circumstances?
>
> *who is* that person?
>   *where is* the store?
>   *when was* the incident?

However, the idiomatic phrase you are using

> no matter what
>
> no matter who
>   no matter where
>   no matter when

is used to mean "always" or "anyone" or "anytime", which then leaves

> no matter what, the circumstances *are*
>   no matter who, that person *is*
>   no matter where, the store *is*
>   no matter when, the incident *was*

which are the commonly used statements.

Comment: I think you've got it wrong. It's awkward because of the subject-auxiliary inversion, which is not required. It's not a 'superlative' but an 'exhaustive conditional' construction, with "no matter" as head of the adjunct with the subordinate interrogative _what_ clause as complement. The meaning is 'I wouldn't do that if the circumstances are x, and I wouldn't do that if the circumstances are y, and so on. It follows that I wouldn't do that under x, y, or any other possible circumstances. Can you see the conditional meaning?

Comment: I see the conditional and "no matter what" emphasises "always", maybe superlative wasn't the right word.

Comment: What is a "commonly statement?"